# Alignment not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, galleria

I'm working on a Galleria gallery and I'm in the finishing stages. It is working for all browsers completely, except for Internet Explorer. I looked around quite a bit and tried all sorts of different solutions offered in the various css columns that might cause the issue, but without luck.

http://sviserver.com/company/rond/index.html

This is the webpage.

http://jsfiddle.net/dBduc/

This is my jsfiddle. It does not work properly, but includes all the code I used. I included a screenshots so you know what is wrong with it. Hopefully someone can see the one thing I'm missing to make it work properly.

```
left is correct, right is in Internet Explorer
```

[image: Left is correct, right one is Internet Explorer]

Comment: It would help to know which version of Internet Explorer it doesn't work in.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. Its version 8. I haven't tried it in 9 yet, all pc's are running on Windows XP atm here.

Comment: show us the code.. is it in div or table structure ? may be not positioned well...

Comment: Hi codebrain, all the code is in the jsfiddle link.

Comment: @LuukvanAggelen, Images are not loading in jsfiddle. Can you update the source links in jsfiddle? It will certainly help us diagnose the issue.

Comment: Jay Patel, thanks for your reply. I uploaded the entire page on a host and added it to the main post. Hopefully this can help.